# Publish ASP.NET web app project without debug=true needed

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a web app project and when running long tasks while debugging it works well. When I publish it, it just times out. We found out that if we set the tag debug=true, it works again (production server). Of course, it's not permitted to leave it like that. What could I do about this?

Comment: Define "running long tasks".  Web applications generally aren't suited for "long tasks".  They time out for a reason.

Comment: Long is like 15 minutes. It used to work, but around May it suddenly started to time out. Anyway, I know it shouldn't work like that, but it's old software (framework 2.0), so making it asynchronous is not desirable.

Comment: 15 minutes is a *very long time* for an HTTP request to wait for a response.  The application could be timing out, the web server itself could be timing out, the browser could be timing out, etc.  Web applications are *not* suited for this sort of thing.  You can check the various timeout thresholds in the entire stack of relevant components (the web server would be a good start I guess), but that's just soothing the symptom without fixing the problem.  The problem is that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Just to expand on what David is saying: an HTTP request should not take more than a couple of seconds to complete. If it is, you've done something wrong with your design. So you should make the process asynchronous. An initial HTTP request should start the processing, and then you check back later when the results are ready. This long running process should not be in the ASP.NET site itself, you need a separate application (like a Windows service or one of the many available cloud offerings) to do the processing.